# Page broke on webservice url but work on host:port

Tags: webserver

I have a page that always generate 404 for it's web server url, but in the log there's no error, and if I hit the page by host:port, it's loading fine. Looks like something wrong with the web server, but I cannot locate the problem. Anyone see this issue before? Thank you.

Problem solved: webservice plugin has problem, it didn't pick up the map for web servers

Comment: Check out the firewall , maybe some rule is affecting the port 80!

Answer (score 0):

is the port something else than 443 or 80? At least in corporate environments http/s-ports are not the default ones.